Manga where the main character has gone back in time to try and stop the destruction of the world
Looking for a (probably completed) manga where the main character lives in the countryside as a maid for an inn. She has a burn mark on her leg in the shape of a butterfly. She has memory loss, and the family is looking for her. Her maid friend collects the reward for finding her and her family pick her up. She has gone back in time to try and stop the destruction of the world.

This is Infatuation Unwanted.

Plonked right into the world of a novel she once read, Sophie simply wishes to live out the rest of her quiet life in the background. Who could ask for a better place than the sleepy village of Pellun? And it was wonderful, peaceful... until knights came in searching for Lady Amelia. The Amelia Cedric from the most powerful noble family in the Rohatin Empire?! Wait, it can't be... I'm just an extra !

A month before the start of the manhwa, the protagonist woke up as 'Sophie,' a minor character in a novel who has a butterfly-shaped burn mark on her right leg and works at an inn in a sleepy village. The protagonist doesn't possess Sophie's memories, but having read the novel, she knows that Sophie is really a noble named Amelia, who ran away from home five years earlier to escape her brother, Duke Bastian Cedric.



Ever since Amelia ran away, Bastian has been sending search parties after her, throughout the empire. One of Sophie's co-workers rats her out and the next day a group of knights turn up at Sophie's door and take her back to Cedric Manor, where she's greeted enthusiastically by the servants and Bastian. The protagonist claims to have amnesia to explain why she doesn't remember these people.
Near the end of the story, the protagonist learns that a goddess reset time to give Amelia a second chance to seal a rift that destroyed the world when she failed to seal it before.



You can read the full manhwa at Pocket Comics.

thank you so much!!

This is Infatuation Unwanted, also identified here.

Plonked right into the world of a novel she once read, Sophie simply wishes to live out the rest of her quiet life in the background. Who could ask for a better place than the sleepy village of Pellun? And it was wonderful, peaceful... until knights came in searching for Lady Amelia. The Amelia Cedric from the most powerful noble family in the Rohatin Empire?! Wait, it can't be... I'm just an extra !

The protagonist is a pink-haired woman with a butterfly burn mark.

The memory loss isn't quite accurate - she has reincarnated into a book she read, but didn't inherit the owner's memories. The owner had (apparently) run away from home and was discovered and sheltered by the inn, where she works at the start of the story.
The other maids hear about a search for a woman with pink hair and a butterfly burn mark, and immediately realize that it is Sophie.
 
Her friend collects the reward and a knight shows up to escort her back.

Thank you so much!!
